# Create http link in Canvas through Android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am working on a module where we are generating a JPG file through Android App. Here is the sample code.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.banner).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);  
Canvas g = new Canvas(bitmap); 

Paint paint = new Paint(); 
int x = 200; int y = 1850; 
g.drawText("www.google.com", x, y, paint); 
return bitmap;
```

Now we have this requirement of making the above text ("www.google.com") as a hyperlink, so that when user touches or clicks on this text in the JPG, the link gets opened in the browser. The JPG can be opened in any system (mobile or desktop).

How can we achieve this functionality?